# MySQL "For Each"

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I'm trying to make a code question website, like [CodeChef](http://www.codechef.com/).

So far, I have two tables, `problems` and `submissions`.

`problems` consists of a single `id` field which is `auto_increment`ed. (It really has more fields, but they are not relevant.)

`submissions` consists of an `id` field which is `auto_increment`ed, a `problem_id` field which is `foreign key`-ed to `problems.id`, and a `bool` `correct` field.

Here are their (simplified) creation statements:

```
create table problems
(
    id bigint auto_increment primary key not null,
    /* more fields that are unimportant */
);
create table submissions
(
    id bigint auto_increment primary key not null,
    problem_id bigint not null,
    correct bool not null,
    /* more fields */

    foreign key (problem_id) references problems(id)
);
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is the following:

For each `id` in `problems`, return a row consisting of that ID, the number of correct submissions for that problem, and the number of total submissions for that problem.

Basically, I want to use the following query:

```
select
    problems.id,
    sum(submissions.correct),
    count(submissions.id)
from submissions inner join problems
on submissions.problem_id=problems.id and problems.id=[problem_id];
```

where `[problem_id]` goes over every `id` in `problems`.

It seems like I need to use a sub-query, but I tried it and it did not work at all.

How do I create a query to return these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has some defaults.

- You do not specify the grouping criteria for the aggregates you use
- you join, this is a 'for each' per se. You don't need anything else than the join condition you already specified
- Your join should be a left join since maybe there's no correct submission for your problem, leading to 0 results at all in case of an `inner` join.

This is my proposition:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    SUM(IF(s.correct, 1, 0)) AS correct_submissions,
    COUNT(s.id) AS total_submissions
FROM problems p
        LEFT JOIN submissions s ON p.id = s.problem_id
GROUP BY
    p.id
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but can't I just use `sum(s.correct)` instead of `sum(if(s.correct, 1, 0))` since `true` is stored as `1` and `false` is stored as `0`?

Comment: I like your answer the best, though, because you also hit the `left join` point.

Comment: I try to avoid the boolean type, so I cannot answer your question. Try it out :)

Comment: Ah. I see that if I have no submissions for a particular problem, then `sum(s.correct)` is `null` while `sum(if(s.correct, 1, 0))` is `0`, which is what I want. So your answer is even more correct than I previously thought!

Comment: Can you explain this?

Comment: I believe this is just how mysql deals with null and aggregates. `select NULL + 0;` returns `NULL`, while `null` evaluates `false` by itself. ( `select if(null = true, 1, 0);` returns 0)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select
problems.id,
sum(submissions.correct),
count(submissions.id)
from submissions inner join problems
on submissions.problem_id=problems.id 
where problems.id=[problem_id]
group by problems.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need for your query is a `group by` clause:

```
select problems.id,
       sum(submissions.correct),
       count(submissions.id)
from submissions inner join
     problems
     on submissions.problem_id=problems.id
group by problems.id;
```